# Splitting files in Unix using values in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, xml

I have a txt file which has multiple XML records. I have to separate it using `vendorname`. I modified the commands as per my requirement. However, it's giving me 2 error messages:

```
awk: sf.awk:1: /<hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http:\//www.mycompany.com\/header\/v1\">[A-Z]+<\/hdr:vendorname>/{
awk: sf.awk:1:                                         ^ syntax error
awk: sf.awk:1: /<hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http:\//www.mycompany.com\/header\/v1\">[A-Z]+<\/hdr:vendorname>/{
awk: sf.awk:1:                                                               ^ backslash not last character on line
```

if I add a `\` in front of `.`, then it gives me another error message

```
awk: sf.awk:1: /<hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http:\//dwh\.www.mycompany.com\/header\/v1\">[A-Z]+<\/hdr:vendorname>/{
awk: sf.awk:1:                                         ^ backslash not last character on line
```

**Script**

```
/<hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http:\//www.mycompany.com\/header\/v1\">[A-Z]+<\/hdr:vendorname>/{
    split($0, a, "hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http:\//www.mycompany.com\/header\/v1">|<\/hdr:vendorname")
    if (out["file_"a[2]".txt"] == "") {
      out["file_"a[2]".txt"] = $0
    }
    else {
      out["file_"a[2]".txt"]=out["file_"a[2]".txt"]"\n"$0
    }
  }

END {
    for (fic in out) {
      printf out[fic] > fic
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to escape both `/` characters.  Fix typos, get code working, then if you like you can post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't do it like this. Parsing XML using regular expressions simply doesn't work very well. If you post some sample XML (and desired output) I'll give you an illustration of how it can be  done using a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to backslash-escape **both** slashes in `http://`, not just the first one.

Thus, the pattern match should look like,

```
/<hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http:\/\/www.mycompany.com\/header\/v1\">[A-Z]+<\/hdr:vendorname>/
```

Additionally, in your call to `split()`,

1. you shouldn't backslash-escape the forward slashes in the string;
2. you should backslash-escape the double-quote (`"`) after `v1`.

So the string in `split()` should look like,

```
"hdr:vendorname xmlns:hdr=\"http://www.mycompany.com/header/v1\">|</hdr:vendorname"
```